# OnBarcode AndroidBarcode shows on Trail text

Tags: android, barcode, qr-code

I have my Android Application which needs to show a QR code to satisfy my business. I am using OnBarcode.AndroidBarcode.jar to generate the QR code. But it shows "On Barcode Trial" inside the generated QR code as a small red color text. How to get rid of this ?

Comment: buy it http://www.onbarcode.com/purchase/purchase-java-barcode-generator.html or get a free one http://barcode4j.sourceforge.net/

Comment: You answered me.Will this get me QR code generator and will it support for Android ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of purchasing something, you can always use the zebra crossing library. It's free and not too difficult to implement.